# Change css class name inside angularjs controller if else

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to change css class name from angular controller if else loop.

Here is my controller

```
     angular.forEach(data,function(event,key){
                var today = new Date();
                var notifyDates = new Date(event.notifyDate);
                console.log(today);
                $scope.cssClass='badge-important';
                if(notifyDates>today){
                    if(cssClass=='badge-important')
                         cssClass = "badge-important2";
                }
                });
```

css

```
    .badge-important2 {
    background-color:yellow
    }
```

If the condition satisfies i need to change css class to something else.I am doing this because if i use directly the badge-important css class it will be applied for every html element.I need to apply style only if the condition satisfies.I have no idea how to achieve this.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: use `ng-class` in view & conditionally load your class .using `.foeach` & setting up things is cumbersome .

Comment: ^ `ng-class="cssClass"`. Make sure you assign it correctly `$scope.cssClass = "badge-important2";` (don't forget `$scope.`)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `ng-class` directive in template.

For example:

```
<div ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <div ng-repeat="event in app.data" 
       ng-class="event.notifyDate > app.today ?
                 'badge-important2' :
                 'badge-important'">
    {{event.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqmruk8t/9/)

Comment: Note: if `>=` is used instead of `>`, then it's better to set the time to 00:00:00  with (from example above) `this.today.setHours(0,0,0,0);`. This way it will compare it correctly (where the current date will match)

Answer (score 0):

into controller

```
$scope.isMoreImportant = (notifyDates>today && cssClass=='badge-important' )
```

into HTML page

```
ng-class="{'badge-important2':isMoreImportant}"
```

Comment: do i need to add controller code inside if condition?

Comment: @SachinHR you can avoid your previous if statment, simply expose to HTML by $scope the checker boolean "isMoreImportant" about your conditions and ng-class render your CSS class if it is true